# How do I calculate the distance between an object of known size and my camera using VBScript?

Tags: math, vbscript, camera, vision

I know the dimensions of the object and everything about the camera. The distance result needs to be updated at least 4 times per second.

The camera feed comes from a robot with a wLAN connection to a laptop. The laptop runs an application that displays a dashboard of sorts for the robot operator. I have to use this specific app and it only supports VBScript for custom dashboard gauges.

How would I take the image data from the camera feed and then calculate the distance? I don't know a lot about VBScript.

Comment: Measure the dimensions of the object when viewed through the camera, and extrapolate the distance using trigonometry?

Answer (score 0):

d = (FL * RHO * IH)/(OH*SH) 
d = distance to object (mm) 
FL = focal length (mm) 
RHO = real height of the object (mm) 
IH = image height (pixels) 
OH = object height (pixels) 
SH = sensor height (mm)